# $Q$ Transfer via Radiation Formula

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, thermal-radiation

According to the formula:
$$
\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}=\sigma\epsilon A T^4
$$
What does $T$ refer to in a situation where I am modelling the power of radiation from air of temperature  to surface of emissivity $$?

Is it the temperature difference? And if so, would the equation look like this?
$$
\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}=\sigma\epsilon A (T_{2} - T_{1})^4
\hspace{0.5in}or\hspace{0.2in}
\frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta t}=\sigma\epsilon A (T_{2}^4 - T_{1}^4)
$$

Further, what would the equation look like if the surface had greater temperature than the air?

Edit: the source of the formula is from the IBO Exam Data Booklet (https://ibphysics.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/annotated-physics-data-booklet-2016.pdf)

Comment: You should cite the source you're getting this formula from, for clarity.

Comment: Added. Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term $\sigma\varepsilon A T^4$ is used to model the [graybody output power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law)—i.e., the outgoing radiative heat flux from some surface with emissivity $\varepsilon$, area $A$, and temperature $T$, without considering any radiative input.

If that surface entirely faces an environment at temperature $T_\mathrm{env}$, then the *net* output is typically modeled as $\sigma\varepsilon A(T^4-T_\mathrm{env}^4)$ because that environment itself radiates heat toward the surface. (Alternatively, the net rate of heat gain at the surface can be modeled as $\sigma\varepsilon A(T_\mathrm{env}^4-T^4)$.)

Special care may be needed to treat a surrounding environment of gas only (as in our atmosphere), as some wavelengths may be unabsorbed and some radiation passing essentially transparently to outer space ($T\approx 0\,\mathrm{K}$). This can cause the effective temperature of the atmosphere for radiative heat transfer calculations (or the so-called "sky temperature") to differ from the actual temperature.

All these topics are discussed in detail in introductory heat transfer textbooks, e.g., Incropera & DeWitt's *Fundamentals of Heat and Mass Transfer*.